# How do I connect to a 74LS47 decoder in ORCAD capture cis?

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, pspice, orcad

As the question says, I have been trying to connect inputs to a 7447 (7-segment decoder) but I get unknown segments in the pspice simulation, I am using capture CIS and I cannot figure out how to properly connect the power pins,

Here is the circuit that I created,

[image]

And here is the corresponding output,

[image]

When I connect VCC to the power pins, I get unknown states on the pspice simulation, any way I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 74LS47 has open collector outputs, so you will need to add pull-up resistors to get a valid High output when a segment should not be lit.

Comment: thanks, I had to connect the outputs with pull up resistors and it started working.